# Symfony:entities association

Tags: symfony, associations, entities

l have a post that has many social media and each social media has a link when it's published so i did ManyToOne and OneTOMany but i have this error:

> Expected value of type "Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection|array"
>   for association field
>   "ProcessBundle\Entity\Publication#$Publication_Reseaux_Sociaux", got
>   "ProcessBundle\Entity\Reseaux_Sociaux" instead.

Publication Entity:

```
/**
  *@var ArrayCollection $Publication_Reseaux_Sociaux
  * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ProcessBundle\Entity\Publication_Reseaux_Sociaux",
 *     mappedBy="publication",cascade={"persist"})
 *
 */
 public $Publication_Reseaux_Sociaux;


Reseaux_Sociaux Entity:

/**
 *@var ArrayCollection $Publication_Reseaux_Sociaux
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ProcessBundle\Entity\Publication_Reseaux_Sociaux",
 *     mappedBy="Reseaux_Sociaux",cascade={"persist"})
 *
 */
private $Publication_Reseaux_Sociaux;
Publication_Reseaux_Sociaux Entity:
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ProcessBundle\Entity\Publication",
  *     inversedBy="Publication_Reseaux_Sociaux", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="publication_id", referencedColumnName="id")
   */
  protected $publication;
/**
 *  @var ArrayCollection
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ProcessBundle\Entity\Reseaux_Sociaux",
 *     inversedBy="Publication_Reseaux_Sociaux",cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="Reseaux_Sociaux_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $Reseaux_Sociaux;
And this is a part of my code my form:
  ->add('Publication_Reseaux_Sociaux',EntityType::class, [
                'class'    =>Reseaux_Sociaux::class,
                'multiple' => true,
                'expanded' => true,
            ])
```

Answer (score 0):

first problem I see with your code:

you define the `Publication_Resaux_Sociaux` field with these annotations:

```
/**
 *@var ArrayCollection $Publication_Reseaux_Sociaux
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ProcessBundle\Entity\Publication_Reseaux_Sociaux",
 *     mappedBy="publication",cascade={"persist"})
 *
 */
 public $Publication_Reseaux_Sociaux;
```

(I prefer camelCase for property Names and CamelCase for class names, but I won't judge ...). So the class for the field is the same as the property name. However, in your form, the class for the field doesn't match the field name (which it should):

```
  ->add('Publication_Reseaux_Sociaux', EntityType::class, [
            'class'    =>Reseaux_Sociaux::class, 
            'multiple' => true,
            'expanded' => true,
        ])
```

maybe this already solves your problem.

If it doesn't, you should **additionally** try the following: use a [`CollectionType`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html#entry-type) with `entry_type` `EntityType`. The `CollectionType` will always return/set a collection/array.